# Visual Studio Code 1.78.2-1.80 is not showing the process name reliably in the terminal tab. Why?

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal

I remember that VS Code used to say the current command that's running in the integrated terminal. But a new updated version doesn't do it anymore it seems...

For example if you run a `git push` the integrated terminal would display `git` instead of `zsh` (see image).

Does anyway know what setting/extension allows this?

```
Version: 1.80.1 (Universal)
```

[image]

Comment: what's the value of your `terminal.integrated.tabs.title` setting? The default is `${process}`. What do you see when you exec a different shell, Ex. `exec bash`? Does the terminal tab title change to "bash"? And what if you open vim? Does it change to "vim"? Does your zsh prompt include anything to change the terminal title?

Comment: also possibly related issue ticket: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/139288

Comment: Thanks for the information @starball digging a bit further it looks like it could be related to this issue here -> https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/172821

Answer (score 2):

This might be an instance of this bug: [Terminal process title not updating #172821](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/172821)- <sup><sub>a fix for which was just committed soon after this question was asked, but got reverting for breaking tests.</sub></sup> The release milestone for the fix is the July 2023 release. People are confirming in the issue ticket that it has been fixed in version 1.84. The PR that purportedly fixed the issue is [node-pty@1.1.0-beta5 #194611](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/194611).

Also potentially related could be [Terminal title not set by xterm control sequence on Windows unless it is a path
#159420](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/159420) which has been fixed and I'm guessing will be released in the January 2024 release.