# Terminal > Integrated > Tabs: Title ${cwdFolder} is not working

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal

variable `${cwdFolder}` doesn't seem to work for me.
Here, after separator (`-`) it should show current directory, for this example it should be "Test5":

[cwdFolder isn't here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9eds.png)

Shell integration is enabled:

[shell integration settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZoni.png)

OS: Windows 10

VSCode Version: 1.81.0 (user setup)

Commit: 6445d93c81ebe42c4cbd7a60712e0b17d9463e97

Date: 2023-08-02T12:37:13.485Z

Electron: 22.3.18

ElectronBuildId: 22689846

Chromium: 108.0.5359.215

Node.js: 16.17.1

V8: 10.8.168.25-electron.0

OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19045

I tried switching console type, but with no results. Also i tested if other variables in

> Terminal > Integrated > Tabs: Title

are working, but they work just fine, except `${cwdFolder}`

Comment: loosely related, but not the same problem I think, since you have stuff partially showing up correctly: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76751989/11107541